# iOS Background Fetch and completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, appdelegate

I am trying to define this method

```
- (void)backgroundFetchWithCompletion:(void(^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler;
```

However I am getting an error on UIBackgroundFetchResult saying a parameter list without types is only allowed, I was following this tutorial and this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/) and that is how they define their method.

Comment: `UIBackgroundFetchResult` not a block it's enum?
UIBackgroundFetchResult is return type maybe?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @Paulw11 my code is what I have posted. Its just a method declaration.

Comment: I pasted your code into Xcode and I didn't get any errors - I suggest you look at surrounding code in case you have missing brackets or braces

Answer (score 4):

After executing some operation at the end you must call one in list.

Objective-C

1. `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);`
2. `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);`
3. `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);`

Swift

1. `completionHandler(.NewData)`
2. `completionHandler(.Failed)`
3. `completionHandler(.NoData)`

Full Examples:

Objective-C

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  NSLog(@"performFetchWithCompletionHandler");
  //Perform some operation
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  println("performFetchWithCompletionHandler")
  //Perform some operation
  completionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[edit] This was an older answer of mine, refer to AbdullahDiaa's answer below for a better/more correct resolution.

I was just experiencing the same issue, and the solution was to add this to the  file where the method with that block was defined:

`#import "AppDelegate.h"`

Comment: It's ``#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`` not AppDelegate.h

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you import UIKit.h in header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```